Finding the equation of a line, knowing a relation among the distances to it from three vertices of a given triangle
I came across this problem in a book. In this problem, we are given three points A, B and C which represent the vertices of a triangle.

My try:
Assuming the line to be $ax + by +c = 0$, and because it passes through the origin, $c$ = 0.
Now, using the distance formula, the distance $P_{2}$ of the point $B(4,3)$ from the line is $ \left| \frac{4a+3b}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\right|$ similarly, $P_{1}$ and $P_{3}$ are $ \left| \frac{ax_{1} + by_{1}}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\right|$ and $ \left| \frac{2a - ax_{1} - by_{1}}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\right|$ respectively.
Now, $P_{1} + P_{3} = P_{2}$ gives us $4a+3b = 2a$ and thus, $2a = -3b$.
On replacing the value of $b$ in the equation of the line, we arrive at the equation $3x-2y=0$, which is option (D). But the correct answer is option (A). I verified the equation which I got by putting the value of point $B$ in the distance formula and it checks out with the condition which is given in the problem and furthermore, option (A) also satisfies it. How can I arrive at option (A) and what is wrong with option (D)?

You arrived at $2a=-3b$ while assuming $a,b > 0,$ which is a contradiction. So in a way, you eliminated the case $a,b > 0.$ But even then you made some mistake because the correct answer also says $x-2y=0.$

Instead of using distances formula and long way to get the answer , we use this fact that the sum of distances from the line $l$ is three times of the distance from the center of triangle from that line. The coordinates of center G of triangle is:
$x_G=\frac{x_1+2-x_1+4}3=2$
$y_G=\frac{y_1-y_1+3}3=1$
If the foot of a perpendicular from G on line $l$ is M then we may write:
$P_1+P_2+P_3=3 GM$
The vertices of triangle are on both sides of the line so we have:
$P_1+P_3-P_2=3 GM$
But $P_1+P_3=P_2$ due to the atatement, so we have:
$GM=0$
That is the line goes through the center of triangle, so we must find the equation of OG:
$y-0=\frac{1-0}{2-0}(x-0)$
Which gives:
$x-2y=0$
So the option A is correct.

Maybe you should write "the sum of the SIGNED distances from the line  is three times the SIGNED distance of the center of the triangle from that line".

@Intelligentipauca, No problem,  or it is better to  say algebraic sum of distances.
